# How to efficiently track unprocessed records in database?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, bigdata

I have a table in a database that is continuously being populated with new records that have to be simply sent to Elasticsearch.

Every 15 minutes the table accrues about 15000 records. My assignment is to create a `@Scheduled` job that every 15 minutes gathers unprocessed records and post them to Elasticsearch.

My question is what is the most efficient way to do it? How to track unprocessed records efficiently?

My suggestion is to employ a column `INSERTED_DATE` that is already in this table and each time persist the last processed `INSERTED_DATE` in an auxiliary table. Nevertheless, it can happen that two or more records were inserted simultaneously but only one of them was processed? Surely there must be other corner cases that discard my approach.

Could you share any thoughts about it? For me it looks like a typical problem for Data Intensive application but I face it for the 1st time in a real life.

Comment: You could process data where the INSERTED_DATE is < current_date - 5 seconds. Then you don't have a problem with data that is inserted in the same moment as you select the data

Comment: Than data duplication is possible. Elasticsearch will prevent it but in case anything else is introduced in the workflow the data won’t be consistent anymore.

Comment: What will be inconsistent?

Comment: Imagine that besides Elasticsearch I sent records the to a system that can’t prevent data duplication. It will lead to different number of records in Elasticsearch and that system

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean by "it can happen that two or more records were inserted simultaneously but only one of them was processed" what's the problem?

Comment: I use Hibernate Stream to fetch records from db and send them in batches where each batch is equal to 1000 records. 2 records with the same date time may end up in different batches and one of the batches can fail to be sent (network exception)

Comment: Then you have to resend it. I really don't understand your problem